# Celery task cannot be called (missing positional arguments) from Django app

Tags: python, django, task, celery, delay

Ok I've poured over all the SO posts, Celery docs, etc...and I just cannot figure this out. No matter what I try or how I try to call a task from a Django app, Celery is complaining that I'm not supplying the required parameters.

> "TypeError: add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'".

I'm following a very simple example from their docs...simply using delay, such as:

```
add.delay(1, 2)
```

and still the same error. I've also tried `add.delay(x=1, y=2)`, `celery.send_task("add", [1, 2])` and a wide variety of other ways I've seen tasks called in various posts and none of them work.

The method is very simple:

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I've also tried it named, such as:

```
@task(name="my_add")
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Same results. What else can I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 7):

First of all you should add more information on your post related with your Django & Celery Configuration.

But I think that your mistake is on the @task decorator, because it seems that you'd need to use the **Bound tasks**:

- A task being bound means the first argument to the task will always
  be the task instance (self), just like Python bound methods. [Reference](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks).
- For the other hand, the **bind** argument means that the function will be a “bound method” so that you can access attributes and methods on the task type instance. [Reference](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#example)

So your code should looks like:

```
import celery

@task(bind=True, name="my_add")
def add(self, x, y):
    return x + y
```

> Notice that the **bind argument** to the task decorator will give access to self (the task type instance).

Finally I recommend to you review again the [Celery setup on Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: Great answer. I ran into the same problem and this fixed it. I don't understand why, though: without binding the method, it seems like I should just be able to decorate a function and pass in args. In my case the reference to self is unnecessary. I'm using flask.

Comment: This solved my issue, I was using `@classmethod` and then `@celery.task()` one after the other. I think celery was not able to get the `cls` param. And perhaps, `bind=True` provided the `cls (or self)` param to the task.